# if else, show and hide menu not working

Tags: jquery

I am creating a menu which show and hides on click. The show works, so when I click my hamburger the divs appear. However on the second click once class 'open' is active, my divs do not hide again. Is my syntax correct.

```
$(".ham").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('closed')) {
        $(this).find(".hamburger").removeClass( "closed" );
        $(this).find(".hamburger").addClass( "open" );
        $(".menu1").css("display", "block");
        $(".menu2").css("display", "block");
        $(".menu3").css("display", "block");
        $(".menu4").css("display", "block");
        $(".logo").removeClass("fadeIn").addClass("fadeOut");
        setTimeout(function(){ $(".logo2").css("display", "block") }, 500);
    }
    else{
        $(this).find(".hamburger").addClass( "closed" );
        $(this).find(".hamburger").removeClass( "open" );
        $(".menu1").css("display", "none");
        $(".menu2").css("display", "none");
        $(".menu3").css("display", "none");
        $(".menu4").css("display", "none");
        $(".logo").removeClass("fadeOut").addClass("fadeIn");
        setTimeout(function(){ $(".logo2").css("display", "none") }, 500);
    }
});

 <div class="ham closed">
       <div id="burger" class="hamburger animated fadeIn">
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
       </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu row">
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 menu1 animated fadeInUp">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 menu2 animated fadeInDown">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 menu3 animated fadeIn">
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 menu4 animated fadeInRight">
     </div>
  </div>

.menu1 {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 999999;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: no error is displayed, the else statement dose not run. @TreeNguyen. I am now adding html

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: @beertwenty could you include the relevant css also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you.

```js
$(".ham").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('closed')) {
        $(this).removeClass( "closed" );
        $(this).addClass( "open" );
        $(".menu1,.menu2,.menu3,.menu4").css("display", "block");
        $(".logo").removeClass("fadeIn").addClass("fadeOut");
        setTimeout(function(){ $(".logo2").css("display", "block") }, 500);
    }
    else{
        $(this).addClass( "closed" );
        $(this).removeClass( "open" );
        $(".menu1,.menu2,.menu3,.menu4").css("display", "none");
        $(".logo").removeClass("fadeOut").addClass("fadeIn");
        setTimeout(function(){ $(".logo2").css("display", "none") }, 500);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ham">
       <div id="burger" class="hamburger animated fadeIn">
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         <div></div>
         Ham
       </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu row">
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 menu1 animated fadeInUp">
     menu1
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 menu2 animated fadeInDown">
     menu2
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 menu3 animated fadeIn">
     menu3
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 menu4 animated fadeInRight">
     menu4
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this has worked. What did I miss?

Comment: You are removing closed class for some other element

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the code for menu items, instead of repeating it. And 'open' and 'closed' classes should be assigned to 'ham' instead of 'hamburger'.

Here is the modified JS code for you:

```js
$(".ham").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('closed')) {
    $(this).removeClass("closed").addClass("open");
    $(".menu1,.menu2,.menu3,.menu4").css("display", "block");
    $(".logo").removeClass("fadeIn").addClass("fadeOut");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".logo2").css("display", "block")
    }, 500);
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("closed").removeClass("open");
    $(".menu1,.menu2,.menu3,.menu4").css("display", "none");
    $(".logo").removeClass("fadeOut").addClass("fadeIn");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".logo2").css("display", "none")
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ham">
  <div id="burger" class="hamburger animated fadeIn">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    Ham
  </div>
</div>
<div class="menu row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 menu1 animated fadeInUp">
    menu1
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 menu2 animated fadeInDown">
    menu2
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 menu3 animated fadeIn">
    menu3
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 menu4 animated fadeInRight">
    menu4
  </div>
</div>
```